# Google spreadsheet sorting script with ignored characters?

Tags: google-apps-script

First of all, I'm really sorry if this question has already been answered. I have a very basic grasp of all things scripting so I wouldn't be surprised if I have already come across an answer to my question without realizing it (because it went way over my head)...

I have a large inventory spreadsheet that I would like to sort alphabetically, but many of the items in the inventory have various prefixes preceding their first principle word which I would like to sort by. Is it possible to create a script that I can designate a set of strings or characters that should be ignored in the sorting? I have seen a lot of suggestions while searching for an answer that involved generating a new column based on a designated delimiter, but I don't think this method will work for me due to items in the inventory not having a consistent prefix (or prefixes). When I tried this suggestion, the principle word I would like to sort by for each item is a different column depending on the item name. Hopefully this makes sense... If anyone as a template, or even just a link to get me started on creating a script like this, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I imagine that any script or formulae will need to be written to either A) discover one or a few text patterns  wherein each of your items will fit that pattern; OR B) that you have a finite list of all the words that you want to sort for, and the script loops through each of the items in your spreadsheet and looks up if one of your sort words is contained within.  You could sift through your data and post here all the examples of each text patterns within your data that your data matches.  (If there are not a few patterns that cover all the data in your spreadsheet, then it is plan B).

Comment: To give you some text pattern ideas:  4th character is usually the start of the first word but if it's the fifth then the fourth is always a number; there are some characters, THEN A SPACE, then the word to be searched on; before the word to be searched on there is always a character of type number or letter X.

Comment: The inventory is a long list of chemicals with some long and ridiculous names. I want to sort by first principle word, here are a few examples: 1) D-**A**lanine 2) Cis-3-(N-Tert-**B**utoxycarbonylamino)cyclopentanecarboxylic acid 3) (1R,2S,5R)-(-)-**M**enthyl (S)-p-toluenesulfinate  My thinking is it would be easier to set something up where it sorts, but I tell it to ignore a specific set of strings that I input: '(' 'N-' 'cis' 'trans' etc... Thanks for your suggestions though, hopefully I can figure something out.

Answer (score 1):

I am standing on Serge's shoulders with this example below, using a regular expression to match for the larger words in your sample (5 or more letters ... you can vary this, but {7,} is the highest which will match both Menthyl and Alanine. Of course Butoxycarbo... is also matched since it is much longer.):

```
function test2(){
         Logger.log(sort2( ['(1R,2S,5R)-(-)-Menthyl (S)-p-toluenesulfinate' ,'D-Alanine','Cis-3-(N-Tert-Butoxycarbonylamino)cyclopentanecarboxylic acid']));
       }


      function sort2(array){
          array.sort(function(x,y){
            var xp = x.match(/\b[A-z]{5,}\b.*$/m);
            var yp = y.match(/\b[A-z]{5,}\b.*$/m);
            return xp == yp ? 0 : xp > yp ? -1 : 1;// replace xp > yp with xp < yp for ascending order 
            });
          return array  
      }
```

Comment: Thanks Serge.  Also, for the OP, you can go to regexpal.com and test out your variation of the regex on some of your sample data. (BTW, you are not likely to get a perfect regex that will match all of your data ... so Serge's comment to combine tactics makes sense.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with arrays, here is an example where I sort descending on the first Character after a space (in lowerCase).

You can chose other parameters in the sort function.

```
function test(){
  Logger.log(['xyz 123','wxy 234','vwx 345','abc 456',])
  Logger.log(sort(['xyz 123','wxy 234','vwx 345','abc 456',]))
 }
function sort(array){
    array.sort(function(x,y){
      var xp = x.toLowerCase().substring(x.indexOf(' ')+1);
      var yp = y.toLowerCase().substring(y.indexOf(' ')+1);
      return xp == yp ? 0 : xp > yp ? -1 : 1;// replace xp > yp with xp < yp for ascending order 
      });
    return array  
}
```

Log output :

```
[xyz 123, wxy 234, vwx 345, abc 456]
[abc 456, vwx 345, wxy 234, xyz 123]
```

As you can see, it is sorted on numbers after the space (descending)

Comment: I didn't have your 'real  life'example when suggesting my answer,  David's answer is more efficient and will most probably suit your needs...you can also combine both if necessary .